# Matrix vector multiplication using BLAS taking more time than for loop

Tags: c, optimization, matrix-multiplication, blas

I am using the following code to multiply matrices:

```
 cblas_sgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, n, n, 1, (float *)A, n, B, 1, 1.0f, C, 1);
```

Where A is a n x n matrix, and B is n x 1 matrix.

The alternative is to do it the usual way -

```
for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      C[i] += A[i * n+ k] * B[k];
```

Surprisingly, the Blas implementation is taking more time than the for loop version. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Which BLAS implementation did you use? What are the timings? Which `n` did you test? What is the target platform (and compilers)? How did you measure the timings? These parameters are very important to understand the problem and answers the question correctly without (probably wrong) guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the documentation for that function here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1513065-cblas_sgemv

... then it's a pretty complex function able to handle different memory layouts, apply a scaling factor, optionally transpose, use an arbitrary stride across rows and columns that probably isn't subject to constant folding if calling the function requires going across module boundaries, etc.

So that's a whole lot more to do, and with the compiler having much less compile-time information to optimize against, than your simple loop version. Where I think it could have an edge in performance is if your matrices are extremely large. Then the BLAS implementation might be able to manually use SIMD in ways that beat your most aggressive optimizers, parallelize the loop, use loop tiling, etc. But those methods usually only provide improvements to justify their overhead when used against especially large matrices, at which point the extra overhead to handle all those extra parameters and the cost of the indirect function call would also be trivialized.

If `n` in your example is sufficiently large (say 1000+), then I would be slightly more surprised that your simple loopy version is beating it, but it still doesn't seem like a huge surprise since that's a pretty complex function that involves a lot of runtime overhead that can't be optimized away (given that it's a dylib API from what I can tell) with all the possible parameters you can specify. If the library is decent, then I suspect it will begin to beat your simple scalar code at some threshold for `n`, but that might require `n` to be quite large, especially given that our optimizers are getting better and better these days at vectorizing our scalar logic.

I'm not familiar with this library but browsing over its API, it's quite generalized in nature. Typically if you want to get the most out of SIMD, you have to organize your data in a certain way suited for your application requirements. For example, if you can represent matrices and vectors in SoA form, then I've found that I can get close to the theoretical boosts in data consumption that SIMD offers (ex: close to 4x with 128-bit registers for SPFP and 8x with 256-bit) and beat my optimizers. But in AoS form doing a single matrix/vector multiplication at a time, I find the speedups far more negligible (say 25% or less), or sometimes even slower than straightforward loops involving scalar instructions that I leave up to my optimizers to vectorize away.

What I would typically expect as far as API design in a library that offers the fastest matrix/vector multiplication is for the multiply function to input an entire container/array of vectors (multiple vectors at once, i.e., against a single matrix). That would generally give it the maximum breathing room to most effectively use parallelization as well as trivializing the overhead of the function call (ex: the branching overhead to determine if scale factors are ~1.0f to determine whether or not an additional multiplication is needed per iteration), and that should have a higher probability of performing well even if your matrices/vectors are on the smaller side provided that you pass in many small vectors at once. There might be a way to do that with your library. If so, I'd give that a shot.